# HTML data attribute not working on my page

Tags: html, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to add a data attribute to an html tag, but it will not work. 
For example:

```
<div class="test" data-id="4"></div>
```

Appears in the browser like this:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

I cannot figure out why the data attribute will not work.

Comment: It seems to work: [Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/kixetepevu/1)

Comment: Yes. It works everywhere else I try it, but not on this page.

Comment: How are you adding the attribute?

Comment: Just like I showed above.

Comment: Have you set your Doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML5)?

Comment: Yes, I have set the doctype.

Comment: Are you using external libraries? like JQuery ...

Comment: Yep, I'm using the latest JQuery library.

Comment: Hm... can we have a look to your site?

Comment: can you try the folowing actions?

1. clear the cache and check

2. remove jquery and check

3. use different attribute for data, for exampe data-myid='4'  and check again ...